# Basic scenario of navigating to another page based on a row clicked in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table with a bunch of items. Each row can be clicked (on any columns in this row) and navigate to another page based on the clicked row. I have a javascript file attached to this page where I manage events (clicked row, ...).

In my ASP.NET MVC solution, I would like to choose a goo way to manage this scenario.

Below is the one I think:

My view:

```
<table>
    <tbody>        
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr data-url="@Url.Action("General", "Transport", new { transportID = item.TransportID })">
                <td>aaaa</td>
                <td>bbbb</td>
                <td>cccc</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My js file:

```
$("table.search-transport tbody tr td:not(:first-child)").live("click", function () {
    var url = $(this).parents('tr').data('url');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Because we cannot inject server code inside javascript files, I inject the url directly inside each rows inside my view. When a row is clicked, I get this "specific" url and navigate to it from my javascript file.

I would like to know if this solution is steady enough in an MVC project.

Comment: This solution doesn't have any collision points with MVC pattern. ASP.NET MVC framework is also very liberal, and doesn't place any roadblocks the way ASP.NET does. It simply doesn't care how you get to a page, as long as it can route the request and can render the Razor template.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm wondering if there are better solutions than this one. As you can see, I inject the url (pre-formatted) in each rows... A little redundant, isn't?

Comment: Mine is more of a consideration based on UX, why not put a real normal link (an `a` tag basically) in the table? This will help clearly visualize the action, does not need javascript or jquery to work, will work across all browsers and it will probably be a lot friendlier regarding accessibility...

Comment: @Tallmaris: I like the way a user can click on any cell (column) in the row to navigate to the detail page. If I follow your suggestion, I need to place a link on each cell (columns) in my row. So if I have 10 columns, then I need 10 different links...

Comment: What I meant was to add a single column to the row, with a link to the details... I am assuming that for a single row, all the cells click will go to the same details page right? Of course it was only a usability consideration :) I understand your point of view about having the whole table-row responsive to user clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the comments, Nikola is right in saying that this does not impact the usage of the ASP.NET MVC framework. Injecting the URL into a data field in your case is the only option as far as I can see it (but I am open to other suggestions).

For the js part, I would use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to avoid attaching events to every single cell:

```
$("table.search-transport tbody tr").on("click", "td:not(:first-child)", function () {
  var url = $(this).parents('tr').data('url');
  // also: $(this).parent().data('url'); will work...
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

This will attach the event to each row but fire only when you click on a td which is not the first child. Alternatively, you could attach the whole event once to the table, thus also having the option of adding rows dynamically and still having the event attached; like this:

```
$("table.search-transport").on("click", "tr td:not(:first-child)", function () {
  [...]
});
```